# Chaning the column name with MM-DD date format

Tags: grafana, dashboard

I want to achieve assigning my column names a different alias. Currently my column names are 0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6. I want to change that 0 - displays current day and month, -1 displays yesterday day and month and so on for today and past 6 days.

[Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFChk.png)
[SolutionForCurrent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuu1I.png)

I have a solution for 0 or today’s date in a way that I edit panel in dashboard and + Add Field Override and then Fields with name, and choose 0 and then + Add overwrite property.
There were already some talks on Add and manage variables | Grafana documentation and here Feature request: Time manipulation functions for $__from and $__to · Issue #19265 · grafana/grafana · GitHub but I didn’t find any useful solutions. If anyone knows a solution in this way or any other way I would appreciate?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the only way is to have 5 variables for every date, and derive their value through query to some data source capable of date manipulations. Be aware that not all data sources capable of such a thing.

For example in MySQL it can be done with query

```sql
SELECT 
  DATE_SUB(
    STR_TO_DATE('${__to:date:dd-MM-yyyy}', '%d-%m-%y'), 
    INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Other SQL data sources will be similar, but their respective data parsing and changing functions.

Something like Prometheus will require creation of 10 variables instead of 5: one for every day, and one for every month. Or change of format to something like `ddmm`, and use the same approach as for SQL:

```
day_of_month(vector(${__to:date:seconds}) - 1 * 24 * 60 * 60) * 100
 + month(vector(${__to:date:seconds}) - 1 * 24 * 60 * 60)
```

Comment: My data source is AWS Athena, can you give me some instructions how can I implement using a query variable?

Comment: I'm not familiar, but try something like `parse_datetime('${__to:date:dd-MM-yyyy}', '%d-%m-%y') - interval '1' day`